# Any idea why i am getting this error?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-cms

I am trying to install django-cms in my ubuntu pc. I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 209, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 100, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 202, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 185, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 162, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cms/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    patch_settings()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cms/conf/__init__.py", line 32, in patch_settings
    post_patch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/cms/conf/patch.py", line 26, in post_patch
    settings.CMS_TEMPLATES = tuple(settings.CMS_TEMPLATES) + (
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any idea why is this error coming?

thanks
Edit -1 --
HI guys,
Yes you were rightm i didnt put cms_templates in settings.py. I did it now, but now I am getting this error.

```
DatabaseError at /
```

no such table: cms_page

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:     http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:     1.3
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:

no such table: cms_page

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 234
Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6
Python Path:

['/home/naveen/django_projects/myproject',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip-0.8.3-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']

Server time:     Fri, 25 Mar 2011 15:34:04 -0500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for a `settings.CMS_TEMPLATES`. It's trying to make `None` a tuple which would throw that error.

Make sure you have a `CMS_TEMPLATES` defined.

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/tutorial.html#configuration-and-setup

Answer (score 1):

Your CMS_TEMPLATES settings is None, I have no idea what that is, but I'm guessing it a setting you need to configure somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`settings.CMS_TEMPLATES` is `None`, I believe. It's hard to tell without a sample of the code in question.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to edit 1:

Which commands are you using? Are you following the [tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/)? I guess you did not do:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

If you just wrote your models, this command will **create the tables in the db**. Otherwise the database is empty, which is the reason why Django can't find the `cms_page`table.

Comment: yep, you were right, I deleted the db file and created a new file again nad did syncdb command. It worked well.